# What is the best way to get the date and time in server side?

Tags: asp.net, date, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an asp.net mvc3 project. I have a trouble in this problem that I encounter. I will give a scenario so that it will understand well.

`Scenario:`

I have 2 PC `(PC1(server) and PC2(client))`. For example both two PC has different  date and time let say for `PC1` is `+8GMT Date 8/10/2016`  and for `PC2 +8GMT Date 8/9/2016`. I am using the `PC2` the `client` and i'm using a code for getting the time is `DateTime.Now();` in my controller and the time is display in `label` in one of my views. I tried to adjust the `Date and Time` of the `PC2` the label for displaying t he time also change. What I want is even I change the `Date and Time` in `PC2` it won't affect/change the displayed `Date and Time` in my label it will stick on what the `Date and Time` in the `PC1`.

**`This scenario is i'm using/testing the publish project`**

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but you might consider looking into the `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` method, which converts the value of the DateTime object to UTC.

This way, you may be able to work with a standard time from which you can convert to any time zone you might want to use to display in your application, regardless of server location.

```
DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;    
DateTime utcTime = serverTime.ToUniversalTime;   
string timeZoneId = "some time zone id";
TimeZoneInfo myTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

DateTime label = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, myTime);
```

Comment: Sorry i'm not good enough in explanation but its different for what i am looking for.

Comment: Sorry i was busy last few days. If i use the `.ToUniversalTime`, even I change the `DATE` in the `PC2` the displayed date in the label won't change?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on your description. It seems as if you want your label to always show the time on the server (PC1) when the web page is loaded on the client by calling the site on the server, maybe like https://pc1. What you're doing should accomplish that: the time displayed in your label will be the system time from the server. Changing the time on the client will not affect it.

If you want your client (PC2) to show its local time, you will need to use code that runs on the client, i.e. JavaScript in most cases.
Working with dates in Javascript can be a little different from other languages/expectations, so I suggest reading the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.
Get started with `var currentDate = new Date();`.